# Excel - Find max value in a 2D array with logic

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find the maximum value from the 15 minute interval data that has dates associated with each row seen below:

```
DATE        UOM 00:01-00:15 kW  00:16-00:30 kW  00:31-00:45 kW  00:46-01:00 kW
7/1/2010    KW  907.2           892.8           883.2           883.2
7/2/2010    KW  907.2           849.6           859.2           825.6
7/3/2010    KW  811.2           806.4           806.4           801.6
7/4/2010    KW  763.2           768             758.4           772.8
```

This data is electrical demands for my school's campus, and I'm trying to find peak, partial peak, and off peak maximum demands. There are approximately 4 years of data with each row consisting of a single data.

Peak hours occur during 12:00 - 18:00 hours

Partial Peak occurs during 08:31 - 11:59 & 18:00 21:30

Off Peak occurs during 21:30 - 08:30

I'd like to be able to get those values for each month of each year.  But so far the logic isn't coming to me, and everything I'm looking up just shows me index-match tutorials.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `MAX` or a combination of two `MAX` functions in order to determine maximums for any given timespan.

[image: Peak Values]

In my screenshot, you can see how the ranges are defined by the columns. Therefore you may have to adjust the ranges to correspond to your actual spreadsheet.

For example, for cell `CW1` it uses the formula `=MAX($AY2:$BV2)`. This determines the value of the maximum value for all 15-minute time spans within that range. Because 12:01 occurs in column `AY`, and 18:00 ends in column `BV`, it's possible to find the maximum between 12:01 - 18:00 by using the `MAX` function.

For time spans that are not continuous, we can split them into multiple ranges. For `CX` and `CY` we do this by using two `MAX` functions. So a maximum value is retrieved for each continuous time span, and then the outer `MAX` determines the maximum of the two local maximums.

Therefore, for `CX`:

```
=MAX(MAX($AK2:$AX2),MAX($BW2:$CJ2))
```

For `CY`:

```
=MAX(MAX($C2:$AJ2),MAX($CK2:$CT2))
```

Note that I don't have your full data set, so these values are garbage.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the click and drag option.  There at 1462 rows, and the columns go to "CU." Obviously If I can't figure anything out, that is what I'll have to do.  Which would be a bummer.

Comment: @Dillon: Unless your data is structured differently than you've described, dragging the formula down to fill those cells is incredibly simple. With Excel, the simplest approach is usually the best approach. Use VBA if it's truly necessary.

Comment: It is incredibly simple, but I'd have to 144 times to accomplish what I'd want.  While that is the simplest, it might also be the longest... :\

Comment: @Dillon: Can you post a better structure of you data? I may be able to assist you better. I'm not seeing how you counted 144 times.

Comment: The dates extend from 7/1/2010 to 6/30/2014 which is about 1462 rows (each row being a date). The 15 minute intervals extend from 00:00 to 24:00 (in 00:15 intervals).  So there are 48 months in 4 years, and I have to figure out the max demand of the three time regimes, so 48*3 = 144 iterations.

Comment: @Dillon: Please check my update and let me know if this is suitable.

Comment: @Dillon: Is this working for you? Please let me know so I can update my solution accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help.  I realized that after posting this the timing on the scheduling were very complex and required a ton of logic for each, here is a screenshot of scheduling logic that I had to work out; http://imgur.com/FdSwNOp   So I ended up doing what you did; breaking up the three rate schedules, but needed to incorporate that other logic.  It ended up working nicely, but just a ton of logic...

Comment: [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mkkehhv0y45er8x/Calculator%20Logic.txt?dl=0) is a dropbox link to a text file that has the logic associated with each time, and the logic to read it into the other sheet. Here is the sheet that I ended up making; http://imgur.com/jEHMI8Z